# ** Error opening port: /dev/ttyUSB0 when receiving: usb 1-1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0

Tags: usb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, usbipd

I am trying to connect to a USB device through WSL.
When I run `dmesg | grep tty` I get the following:

```
[45309.716846] usb 1-1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[45452.900614] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[69001.923677] usb 1-1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[71322.315854] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[71343.176583] usb 1-1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[71381.939112] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[72354.837801] usb 1-1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[90634.845104] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[90648.157900] usb 1-1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

At the end the device is attached.
However, when I run a shell file to connect to the port, everything works fine up until opening the port, I receive this at the end:

```
** Error opening port: /dev/ttyUSB0
```

It is just this message, nothing about permissions etc

I am not sure why there is an error connecting to the port?